# Reading and writing a json file in python

Tags: python, json

I want to make a program that reads a json file and if it does not exist, create that file
with some default parameters. The issue i am having is that the following code does not work.

```
import json
 
file_json = '/home/sga/Documents/Python/dracula.json'
font = ''
with open(file_json) as file:
  data = json.loads(file.read())
  if 'font' in data:  
      font = data['font']  
  else:              
      with open(file_json, 'w') as file_data:
          data['font'] = 'UbuntuMono'     
          data_encoded = json.dump(data)  
          file.write(data_encoded)
```

when I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sga/Documents/Python/Proof/font.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = json.loads(file.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

the json file I have is the following:

```
{
    "dark": [
        "#292d3e",
        "#292d3e"
    ],
    "grey": [
        "#434758",
        "#434758"
    ],
    "light": [
        "#ffffff",
        "#ffffff"
    ],
    "text": [
        "#292d3e",
        "#292d3e"
    ],
    "focus": [
        "#A77AC4",
        "#A77AC4"
    ],
    "urgent": [
        "#ff5555",
        "#ff5555"
    ],
    "active": [
        "#f1ffff",
        "#f1ffff"
    ],
    "inactive": [
        "#4c566a",
        "#4c566a"
    ],
    "color1": [
        "#ff5555",
        "#ff5555"
    ],
    "color2": [
        "#A77AC4",
        "#A77AC4"
    ],
    "color3": [
        "#7197E7",
        "#7197E7"
    ],
    "color4": [
        "#ffb86c",
        "#ffb86c"
    ]
}
```

and the result I want to have after executing it is the following:

```
{
    "dark": [
        "#292d3e",
        "#292d3e"
    ],
    "grey": [
        "#434758",
        "#434758"
    ], 

   ...

   "font" : "UbuntuMono"
}
```

Comment: Try `open(file_json, ecoding="utf-8-sig")`. Also you can use `json.load(file)`

Comment: Please write a clear description of your problem.  Your disorganized, run-on text is difficult to interpret.

Comment: Hello thanks for your attention but I keep getting the same error
that I had before, I already tried
change `open(file_json, ecoding =" utf-8-sig ")`

Comment: `" utf-8-sig "` ≠ `"utf-8-sig"` (and that should probably be `encoding` instead of `ecoding`)

Answer (score 0):

Made a few edits, but this does what you want. Be aware of when to use json.load/loads and json.dump/dumps.

```
font = ''
data = json.load(open(file_json)) # load for file, not loads
if 'font' in data:  
    print('Yes font')
    font = data['font'] 
else:              
  with open(file_json, 'w') as file_data:
      data['font'] = 'UbuntuMono'     
      data_encoded = json.dumps(data)  # dumps, not dump
      file_data.write(data_encoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

So i assume you are after something like this. This is just some quick code to point you in the right direction.

```py
import json
import os

file_json = 'dracula.json'
font = ''


# Not sure if in your case you need this but if the file does not exist then create it.
if not os.path.exists(file_json):
    with open(file_json, "w") as fw:
        json.dump({"font": "UbuntuMono"}, fw, indent=2)

# if the file exists then read it.
with open(file_json, "r") as fr:
    data = json.load(fr)

# this is where we check to see if the key you have asked for is present.
if 'font' in data:
    font = data['font']
    print(f"Found font {font}")
# if we didnt find the key then back fill the value into the data
else:
    with open(file_json, "w") as fw:
        data['font'] = 'UbuntuMono'
        json.dump(data, fw, indent=2)
```

Comment: Please up vote or accept the answer if it helps you resolve your issue.